# How to invoke multiple oracaliszed queries from a single contract

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, myetherwallet, cpp-ethereum, oracles

I want to invoke 2 different orcalized queries from the same contract. I saw a few posts but none of the answer works. Is there any way we can do that? Here is my contract. I was expecting this contract to log both `11111111` and `222222222222222` but it prints error `VM Exception: invalid opcode` I am using http://dapps.oraclize.it/ . When I call single query it works but not 2 queries.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/strings.sol";

contract verifySettlement is usingOraclize {

    uint public price;
    string public landingtime;
    string public expectedtime;`
    string public tempvalue;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint) queries;

    event Log(string text);

    function verifySettlement() payable {
        Log("Contract created.");
        getActualFlightDetails();
        getExpectedFlightDetails();
    }

    function getActualLandingHour() constant returns (string) {
       return landingtime;
    }

    function getExpectedLandingHour() constant returns (string) {
       return expectedtime;
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
        require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
        if(queries[_myid] == 1)
        {
            Log("1111111111111111111111111");
        }
        if(queries[_myid] == 2)
        {
            Log("2222222222222222222222222222222");
        }
        //Log(_result);
        //tempvalue = _result;
    }

    function getActualFlightDetails() payable {
        Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer for getting actual flight details..");
        queries[oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/actual/flight/1")]=1;
        //queries[oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/expected/flight/1")]=2;
    }

    function getExpectedFlightDetails() payable {
        Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer for getting actual flight details..");
        //queries[oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/expected/flight/1")]=1;
        queries[oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/expected/flight/1")]=2;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter `id` in the `__callback`will handle different requests in the same callback function.

```
contract verifySettlement is usingOraclize {

 uint public price;
 string public landingtime;
 string public expectedtime;`
 string public tempvalue;


  event Log(string text);

  enum oraclizeState { ForActual, ForExpected }

   struct oraclizeCallback {
        oraclizeState oState;
  }
  mapping (bytes32 => oraclizeCallback) public oraclizeCallbacks;

function verifySettlement() payable {
    Log("Contract created.");
    getActualFlightDetails();
    getExpectedFlightDetails();
}

function getActualLandingHour() constant returns (string) {
   return landingtime;
}

function getExpectedLandingHour() constant returns (string) {
   return expectedtime;
}

function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
     require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
     oraclizeCallback memory o = oraclizeCallbacks[myid];
             if (o.oState == oraclizeState.ForActual) {
                           Log("1111111111111111111111111");
              }
              else if(o.oState == oraclizeState.Forxpected) {
                           Log("2222222222222222222222222222222");   
             }
}

function getActualFlightDetails() payable {
    Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer for getting actual flight details..");
     bytes32 queryId=oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/actual/flight/1");
     oraclizeCallbacks[queryId] = oraclizeCallback(oraclizeState.ForActual);
}

function getExpectedFlightDetails() payable {
    Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer for getting actual flight details..");

     bytes32 queryId=oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/expected/flight/1");
      oraclizeCallbacks[queryId] = oraclizeCallback(oraclizeState.ForExpected);
}
 }
```

To keep track of the different queries we have used struct to hold and defined a mapping between queryids and state of query.