# Request multiple API endpoints in Oraclize call

Tags: solidity, oracles

I want to make calls to multiple API endpoints. In my case, this is because I don't want to store the whole JSON response in my contract.

If I wanted to get the `?color=red` and `?color=blue` endpoints, could I use a call like this?

```
oraclize_query("URL",
               "json(http://my.api.com/).thing.stuff.0",
               "color=red",
               "color=blue");
```

This is a total guess. And it wouldn't allow me to pick out different JSON paths (thing.stuff.0), which I would want.

But I don't see any documentation about it. I am going off this piece of the [source code](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol):

```
contract OraclizeI {
    address public cbAddress;
    function query(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg) external payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function query_withGasLimit(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg, uint _gaslimit) external payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function query2(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg1, string _arg2) public payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with ```callback```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter `id` in the `__callback`will handle different requests in the same callback function.The following is the example dealing with multiple requests.

```
          contract verifySettlement is usingOraclize {

           uint public price;
           string public landingtime;
           string public expectedtime;`
           string public tempvalue;


            event Log(string text);

            enum oraclizeState { ForActual, ForExpected }

            struct oraclizeCallback {
                  oraclizeState oState;
            }
            mapping (bytes32 => oraclizeCallback) public oraclizeCallbacks;

          function verifySettlement() payable {
                   Log("Contract created.");
                   getActualFlightDetails();
                   getExpectedFlightDetails();
          }

          function getActualLandingHour() constant returns (string) {
                return landingtime;
          }

          function getExpectedLandingHour() constant returns (string) {
              return expectedtime;
            }

         function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
                 require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
                 oraclizeCallback memory o = oraclizeCallbacks[myid];
                 if (o.oState == oraclizeState.ForActual) {
                           Log("1111111111111111111111111");
                 }
                 else if(o.oState == oraclizeState.Forxpected) {
                       Log("2222222222222222222222222222222");   
                 }
         }

         function getActualFlightDetails() payable {
                   Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer for getting actual flight details..");
                   bytes32 queryId=oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/actual/flight/1");
                   oraclizeCallbacks[queryId] = oraclizeCallback(oraclizeState.ForActual);
          }

         function getExpectedFlightDetails() payable {
                Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer for getting actual flight details..");

                bytes32 queryId=oraclize_query("URL","http://169.53.241.139:5000/expected/flight/1");
              oraclizeCallbacks[queryId] = oraclizeCallback(oraclizeState.ForExpected);
         }
    }
```

References :-  1) https://medium.com/@crissimrobert/setting-up-of-oraclize-service-in-smart-contracts-9693049b2151

2) [How to invoke multiple oracaliszed queries from a single contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40781/how-to-invoke-multiple-oracaliszed-queries-from-a-single-contract/40787#40787)

Comment: This approach is much better than what I was trying!

Comment: I am not going to accept it yet because I would still like to know how to call e.g. query2 or queryN. Along the lines of the query seen [in this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28641/simplest-way-to-use-a-variable-in-an-oraclize-query?noredirect=1&lq=1), where the API parameters are passed as separate arguments in the `oraclize_query ` function call. I really appreciate your reply and have upvoted, however it's not exactly what I was getting at with the question

Comment: Do you need to know regarding dynamic query?How to update query with dynamic param?Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this yet but essentially, you could make a computation call to Oraclize.

```
oraclize_query("computation", ["<IPFS Hash>", ... ])
```

You need to upload a python script to the IPFS network, extracting all values you need from the JSON file and subsequently merging them together into a single string. Here, you can just use for instance a ',' to separate the different results and then add a decode() function to your smart contract for refractoring the string into the different results again.

Hope it helps.